# Eclipse CDT New Project Template - How to add a include path?

Tags: java, c, plugins, eclipse-cdt

How do i add a custom folder in the include path in Eclipse CDT New Project Template ?

I am using the following tag in template/template.xml but not working -

```
<process type="org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.AppendToMBSStringListOptionValues">
    <simple name="projectName" value="$(projectName)" />
    <complex-array name="resourcePaths">
        <element>
            <simple name="id" value="gnu.c.compiler.option.include.paths" />
            <simple name="value" value="/home/utkarshmankad/Documents/Ubimote/Lab_Experiments/sdk" />
            <simple name="path" value="" />
        </element>
    </complex-array>
</process>
```

When running this above written code, the error shows - Argument mismatch type:resourcePaths. With following error log -

> Argument type mismatch: files
>   Argument type mismatch: files
>     No Condition--> Process 1 (org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.NewManagedProject)-->Success: Executed successfully with args: [name:test1, location:/home/utkarshmankad/runtime-EclipseApplication, artifactExtension:exe, isCProject:true]
>     No Condition--> Process 2 (org.eclipse.cdt.core.CreateSourceFolder)-->Success: Executed successfully with args: [projectName:test1, path:src]
>     No Condition--> Process 3 (org.eclipse.cdt.core.AddFiles)-->Success: Executed successfully with args: [projectName:test1, files:{{source:src/basename.c, target:src/test1.c, replaceable:true}, {source:Makefile, target:Makefile, replaceable:false}, {source:Makefile.test, target:Makefile.test, replaceable:false}}]
>     No Condition--> Process 4 (org.eclipse.cdt.ui.OpenFiles)-->Success: Executed successfully with args: [projectName:test1, files:{{target:src/test1.c}}]
>     No Condition--> Process 5 (org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.SetMBSStringOptionValue)-->Success: Executed successfully with args: [projectName:test1, resourcePaths:{{id:.*compiler.option.dialect.std.*, value:ISO C99 (-std=c99), path:}}]
>     No Condition--> Process 6 (org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.SetMBSBooleanOptionValue)-->Success: Executed successfully with args: [projectName:test1, resourcePaths:{{id:.*compiler.option.warnings.extrawarn.*, value:true, path:}}]
>     No Condition--> Process 7 (org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.SetMBSStringOptionValue)-->Success: Executed successfully with args: [projectName:test1, resourcePaths:{{id:.*compiler.option.misc.other.*, value:-c -fmessage-length=0 -Werror, path:}}]

Please help me with right way of adding custom include files in include path ?

Comment: I think it would be simpler to import include paths after creating new project using stock template.

Comment: But is it possible to add a include path the template way ? it is a requirement for a plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found a solution to my problem.

This was possible with the help of a blog article here - https://www.sevenwatt.com/main/eclipse-cdt-plug-ins-new-cc-project-templates/

And little digging up in a simple C project's hidden .cproject file. To identify the id value.

You must put this piece of code to add any folder in your pc to add it to include search path -

```
<process type="org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.AppendToMBSStringListOptionValues">
    <simple name="projectName" value="$(projectName)" />
    <complex-array name="resourcePaths">
        <element>
            <simple name="id" value="gnu.c.compiler.option.include.paths" />
            <simple-array name="values">
                <element value="&quot;/home/utkarshmankad/Documents/Ubimote/Lab_Experiments/sdk/bsp/&quot;" />
                <element value="&quot;/home/utkarshmankad/Documents/Ubimote/Lab_Experiments/sdk/drivers/&quot;" />
            </simple-array>
            <simple name="path" value="" />
        </element>
    </complex-array>
</process>
```

Here, i have added multiple include search paths by adding multiple  Tag.
If you want to only one include path then, keep just one element path.